# How to show datediff progressively by each measurement?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I couldn't articulate my title very well but what I am trying to do is show the difference between two dates progressively until the highest unit of measurement can be used.

What this means is that I want to show the difference initially by seconds using `#DateDiff('s', mydate, Now())#`. After 60 seconds it should show the difference in minutes. After 60 minutes I want it to show the difference by Hours and Minutes together. Then after 24 hours, it should show the difference by Days and Hours. And so on until weeks, months, years are covered.

I can only imagine doing it using a big `<cfif>` statement and just wondered if there's a better way to do it before I start writing this thing.

Comment: Have you looked on CFLib.org? Specifically [ago()](http://cflib.org/udf/ago) looks like it would do what you need.

Comment: No I'll have a look now!

Comment: *if there's a better way* Not really. No matter how you implement it, you will need several comparisons. Also have a look on SO. Here is another version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679323/relative-dates-in-coldfusion . May not be exactly what you need, but you could easily customize it.

Comment: That UDF will do it unless you wish for the remainder (1 day, 4 hours and 30 minutes). But you could pretty easily modify it I would think.

Comment: @MarkAKruger yes I also need to show the remainder but not all the way down to the lowest time measurement. It would be like `1 day, 4 hours ago` or `2 years, 1 month ago` or `1 minute, 26 seconds ago`

Comment: @volumone - got it. Using that UDF, mofify it to append to a string with each IF iteration. should be easy. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfscript>
function CalcAge(Date1,Date2,depth) {
    param name="Arguments.depth" default="0";
    // Only alter local["partlist"] to list the dateparts you want to calculate.
    // Partlist args = cx = century, dx = decade, yyyy = year, m = month, ww = week, d = day, h = hour, n = minute, s = second
    // Partlist should also be in descending order.
    // Known Issue: The last element of partlist must be a coldfusion-recognized datepart (yyyy,m,ww,d,h,n,s)
    local["partlist"] = "cx,yyyy,m,ww,d,h,n,s";
    local["partWords"] = {cx="century,centuries",dx="decade,decades",yyyy="year,years",m="month,months",ww="week,weeks",d="day,days",h="hour,hours",n="minute,minutes",s="second,seconds"};

    local["fDates"] = {};
    // Decide which date is more recent, make the more recent as gDate
    if (DateCompare(Arguments["Date1"],Arguments["Date2"]) == -1) {
        // The First date is earlier than the second date
        local["fDates"]["lDate"] = Arguments["Date1"];
        local["fDates"]["gDate"] = Arguments["Date2"];
    } else if (DateCompare(Arguments["Date1"],Arguments["Date2"]) == 1) {
        // The second date is earlier than the first date, switch them
        local["fDates"]["lDate"] = Arguments["Date2"];
        local["fDates"]["gDate"] = Arguments["Date1"];
    } else {
        // The dates are equal, return and exit.
        return "0";
    }

    local["Difference"]=StructNew();
    local["pString"] = "";
    local["fDates"]["chDate"] = local["fDates"]["gDate"];
    local["cDepth"] = 0;
    while (DateDiff(listLast(local["partlist"]),local["fDates"]["lDate"],local["fDates"]["chDate"]) > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= listlen(local["partlist"]); i++) {
            ix = listGetAt(local["partlist"],i);
            param name="local.Difference.#ix#" default="0";

            if (ix == "cx") { // centuries
                while (DateDiff("yyyy",local["fDates"]["lDate"],local["fDates"]["chDate"]) >= 100) {
                    local["fDates"]["chDate"] = DateAdd("yyyy",-100,local["fDates"]["chDate"]);
                    local["Difference"][ix] += 1;
                }
            } else if (ix == "dx") { // decades
                while (DateDiff("yyyy",local["fDates"]["lDate"],local["fDates"]["chDate"]) > 10) {
                    local["fDates"]["chDate"] = DateAdd("yyyy",-10,local["fDates"]["chDate"]);
                    local["Difference"][ix] += 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (DateDiff(ix,local["fDates"]["lDate"],local["fDates"]["chDate"]) > 0) {
                    local["Changeby"] = DateDiff(ix,local["fDates"]["lDate"],local["fDates"]["chDate"]);
                    local["fDates"]["chDate"] = DateAdd(ix,0-Abs(local["changeby"]),local["fDates"]["chDate"]);
                    local["Difference"][ix] = local["changeby"];
                }
            }

            if (local["Difference"][ix] > 0) {
                local["cDepth"] = local["cDepth"] + 1;
                local["pString"] = listAppend(local["pString"],"#local["Difference"][ix]# #ListGetAt(local["partWords"][ix],min(2,local["Difference"][ix]))#",",");
                if (local["cDepth"] == Arguments["depth"]) {
                    return replace(local["pString"],",",", ","ALL");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return replace(local["pString"],",",", ","ALL");
}

</cfscript>
```

And to use the function:

```
<cfoutput>Adding 13 months. #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("m",13,Now()))#<br><br>
Brief: #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("m",13,Now()),2)#<br><br>

Adding 135 years. #CalcAge(DateAdd("yyyy",135,Now()),Now())#<br><br>
Brief: #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("yyyy",135,Now()),2)#<br><br>

Adding 73 hours. #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("h",73,Now()))#<br><br>
Brief: #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("h",73,Now()),2)#<br><br>

Depth: 100 (because none will have 100 elements); #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),100)#<br><br>
Depth: 4; #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),4)#<br><br>
Depth: 3; #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),3)#<br><br>
Depth: 2; #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),2)#<br><br>
Depth: 1; #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),1)#<br><br>
Depth: 0 (depth 0 means unlimited); #CalcAge(Now(),DateAdd("s",1000000000,Now()),0)#<br><br></cfoutput>
```

This should do exactly what you're looking for.

The first two parameters are dates, should be passed as CalcAge(Date1,Date2).

If you set the third parameter, "depth" to a number, it rounds the age down at the largest unit measured (A depth of 2 would say '6 days, 4 hours' rather than '6 days, 4 hours, 3 minutes, 28 seconds').